# IS there an easy way to add 5 days delay to XMLGregorianCalendar date?

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar

I want to **add 5 days delay to XMLGregorianCalendar date** (date is coming from json request). I tried converting it first to LocalDateTime as follows, this works

```
LocalDateTime date = request.getDate().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime().plusDays(5);
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(date);
```

Another approach I tried was as follows, which is throwing below error

```
Timestamp date = DateUtil.convertToTimestamp(request.getDate().
                                           add(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("P14D"));
```

**Error:**

```
Required type: XMLGregorianCalendar
Provided: void
```

Although, the LocalDateTime one does not give any errors, I am just wondering if there's an easy way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with the first approach? It doesn't get more easy than that?

Comment: What *exactly* does `request.getDate()` return? Is that an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object?

Comment: Why the focus on `Timestamp`? Are you trying to write this to a database? If so, say so, as that affects the Answers.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, I'm trying to write the timestamp value to the database.

Comment: @Coder Then say so in your Question. Click “Edit” to, well, edit.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

*XMLGregorianCalendar ➡️ GregorianCalendar ➡️ ZonedDateTime ➡️ OffsetDateTime*

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject( 
    … , 
    myXMLGregorianCalendar
    .toGregorianCalendar()
    .toZonedDateTime() 
    .plusDays( 5 )
    .toOffsetDateTime()
)
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

When handed a legacy date-time object like `XMLGregorianCalendar`, immediately convert to the modern *java.time* classes. In *java.time*, the replacement class is `ZonedDateTime`.

To get to `ZonedDateTime`, go though another legacy class, `GregorianCalendar`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;
```

### Add days

Add five days. Adjustments are automatically made for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZonedDateTime fiveDaysLater = zdt.plusDays( 5 ) ;
```

### `LocalDateTime` is not a moment

Do not use `LocalDateTime` at all in this situation. That class lacks the context of an offset or time zone, so it cannot be used to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

### Database

If you are trying to write this value to a database, do not use the legacy `Timestamp` class. Use only *java.time* classes. To communicate a moment to a database, use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = fiveDaysLater.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject ( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo"" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use the Timestamp class.  It doesn’t do what you think it does.  In fact, it doesn’t even do what it was originally intended to do all that well (represent a particular SQL type).

Just use the [add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add(int,int)) method of GregorianCalendar:

```
XMLGregoriantCalendar xcal = request.getDate();

GregorianCalendar gcal = xcal.toGregorianCalendar();
gcal.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);

xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcal);
```